# Unexpected behavior when copying columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) with several columns, one of which is loan_status. The breakdown of that column is as follows:

```
Charged Off                                              38029
Current                                                 520784
Default                                                    199
Does not meet the credit policy.  Status:Charged Off       758
Does not meet the credit policy.  Status:Current            15
Does not meet the credit policy.  Status:Fully Paid       1947
Fully Paid                                              176203
In Grace Period                                           6486
Issued                                                     142
Late (16-30 days)                                         2337
Late (31-120 days)                                        9949
```

I want to make a new column that categorizes each entry into a loan in good standing or bad standing, to do so. I did the following:

```
df["badloan"] = df.loan_status
df.loc[(df.badloan == "Charged Off") | 
       (df.badloan == "Default") |      
       (df.badloan =="Does not meet the credit policy.  Status:Charged Off"),
       df.badloan] = "Bad"
```

This gave me the following error:

> ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

This made me realize that there must be some nan values in the data and out of curiosity I ran:

```
df["badloan"] == df.loan_status
```

This resulted in mostly true values but a few false. I then tried re defining df.badloan in case I had accidentally modified it:

```
df["badloan"] = df.loan_status
df["badloan"] == df.loan_status
```

This still produced some false values. Any idea why?

Comment: have you checked whether there are any nans in your column? Try `np.isnan(df.loan_status).any()`.  nan==nan is False, which would explain this behaviour.

Comment: Exactly the issue, did not realize nan!=nan.  Thank you!

Comment: Could you post your false values?

Comment: All the false values were the result of a nan==nan